# Add GObject module in Nuitka

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, pygobject, nuitka

When I compile a GTK based project by Nuitka, it compiles without any error, but when I run the compiled file, it shows this error:

```
  File "/home/morteza/mtodo/src/interface.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

**while when I run the application by Python it works fine**

This is how I compile the project:

```
nuitka3 --recurse-all --standalone --follow-imports bin/mtodo
```

How can I embed the GObject?

Comment: Relevant [`No module named 'gi'`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+No+module+named+%27gi%27)

Comment: @stovfl Thank you, but they didn't address my issue.